# D3 reference svg element by its index i

Tags: d3.js

Can I reference an svg element based on its index?

So for example, I can do `d3.selectAll("circle").on("click", function(d, i) { console.log(i) }` where `i` is the `ith` `<circle>` drawn.

But, given an index `i`, how can I reference the `ith` `<circle>`?

Somehow call it directly like `circle[i].attr("cx").attr("cy")` to get the attributes of that `ith` circle?  Say for example if I want the 5th circle's coordinates without actually knowing which one that is, in this case i=5?

How can I reference an element this way? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the handler

```
d3.selectAll("circle").on("click", function(d, i) { console.log(i) }
```

you have access to the `<circle>` element that was clicked via the `this` keyword (you can `console.log(this)` to see it).

Given access to the DOM element, you can now d3-select it:

```
d3.selectAll("circle")
  .on("click", function(d, i) {
    d3.select(this).attr('fill', 'red');
  }
```

In addition, since you have the DOM node, you can also get its parent via `this.parentNode`, and you can select any of that parent's children (i.e. sibling circles). To select based on `i`, you should be able to use `:nth-child`.

```
d3.selectAll("circle")
  .on("click", function(d, i) {
    d3.select(this.parentNode).select('circle:nth-child' + (i+1))
  }
```

You can also select all the sibling circles and conditionally manipulate them based on their index:

```
d3.selectAll("circle")
  .on("click", function(d, i) {
    d3.select(this.parentNode).selectAll('circle')
      .attr('fill', function(dSibling, iSibling) {
        if(iSibling != i) {
          // Affects all sibling circles EXCEPT the clicked one
          return 'red'
        }
      })
  }
```

Comment: What you suggest is great, but im not trying to reference an element I click on, but rather use the datum index to reference another element.

Comment: @brno792 I added more info